# Fresh loading activity every time of calling it

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In an android App im showing advertisement from a local advertisement company.

My problem is when start App and close it with back button, and back to it by clicking on its icon, i see the same Ad. But when i close the app from android task manager and back to the app, i see another Ad.

I know this can have multiple reasons and my question is not clear, But my main questions that how i can set each activity runs like first time of running the app? What should cause this reaction? its like a cookie system... i want every activity show new Ad!

Here you can see example code:
 http://github.com/adad-project/client-app-sample

Comment: You must be fetching new ID in `onCreate`, do that in `onStart`. If you put some code we shall be able to help you better.

Comment: can you explain about fetching new ID? how? i use an Iranian advertisement company. here you can see example code, i use exact the same code: https://github.com/adad-project/client-app-sample

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
Adad.initialize(getApplicationContext());
((AdView) findViewById(R.id.banner_ad_view)).setAdListener(mAdListener);
```

to `onStart` and remove from `onCreate` in `MainActivity`

Do similar thing in other activities.

Comment: i do this but i get same reaction again. what can cause this? what is difference between closing app from task manager and back button. both of them calls onCreate and all of the things after relaunching... what i have to do...